# Rhythm Game - Checking Collisions + Performance in Unity

Tags: c#, performance, unity-game-engine, game-physics, game-development

I have a basic Stepmania style rhythm game, which uses `AudioSettings.dspTime` for the internal clock, making everything very accurate and not tied to physics updates or framerate.

My problem is checking for which note the player "hit." I could attach 2D Box Colliders to everything, and simply use `BoxCollider2D#OverLapCollider(...)`, but then it ties the player accuracy to when the physics updates, and it seems like a fairly costly command to use, in a situation where reaction time down to milliseconds matters.

Each note object has an internal time of when it should be hit, so a different solution may be to store a list of notes, check against the list when the player presses a button, filter out notes outside of a reasonable range, and go from there. However, that seems more janky than collision checking. Though, I would choose this one over the other for not being tied to physics calculations.

What would be the best solution here, which doesn't impact performance significantly?